# how to get the numeric of 01-Jan with an year input in MatLab

Tags: matlab

When I do `datenum('01-Jan-2001')` I get 730852.

If I have Year = 2001, how do I manage to use `datenum` in a way that MatLab understand that I want the first day of the year to return its `datenum`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Year = 2001;
datenum(Year,1,1);
```

This gives the datenum for first day of, the first month, of *Year*.

The datenum unit is one day.

```
datenum(0,0,1)   % datenum(year, month, day)

ans  =

    1
```

Similarly, the first day of the first month is the same as the first day

```
datenum(0,1,1)

ans  =

    1
```

The datenum for your year, without the first day would be

```
datenum(Year,0,0)

ans  =

    730851
```

To get the first day you can do what I show at the start, or any of the following:

- `datenum(Year,1,1)`
- `datenum(Year,0,1)`
- `datenum(Year,0,0)+datenum(0,1,1)`
- `datenum(Year,0,0)+datenum(0,0,1)`
- `datenum(Year,0,0)+1`